# Furnace fan starts slow and is getting slower

Tags: furnace

here is a sound clip, start at about :55 or listen to whole thing!

https://clyp.it/3h54oe2q

model is tg9s060b12mp11 luxaire, which comes up as York most places.

Anyhow, what's the best way to diagnose if this is a motor problem or a capacitor or whatnot.

Here is how much I know about furnaces - I found out how to take the panels off. And there is a kill switch on the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the capacitor is dead/dying.

If you have a capacitor tester, or a multimeter with a capacitor test feature, you can test the capacitor. There should be a micro farad rating on the capacitor (e,g, 10µF), and a variance percentage. When you test the capacitor, it should be withing the variance percentage. If it's not, then it's bad.  For example a capacitor rated 10µF ±6%, should test between 9.4 and 10.6 micro farad. If not, then it should be replaced.

Comment: Agreed. It's the capacitor or the motor is fried. [What is wrong with my central heating?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3810/what-is-wrong-with-my-central-heating/3828#3828) If the blower's squirrel cage spins freely, it's more likely just the cap.

Comment: The capacitor was good. I bought a new one to try out just in case. I ended up replacing the motor. It was actually a fairly simple repair.